# set unwanted color to transparent

Tags: colors, imagemagick, transparent, crop

let say photoA got 100 color, i want to generate a transparent photoB with only 10 wanted colors. by using -transparent of 90 colors is too troublesome, any idea ?

---

thanks TobiasE, your answer is helpful.

i try the command below,

> convert map.gif +transparent "#26fffe" newmap.gif

but it show error msg below:

> convert: unable to open image `#26fffe': No such file or directory.

any idea ?

Comment: No, that should work. I tried and it did. Have you tried with single-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the colors you want to make transparent is similar to each other you can use the -fuzz setting.
- If the colors you want to keep visible is similar to each other you can use the -fuzz setting and use +transparent instead of -transparent to invert the matched pixels.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent

you are right, i just found the documentation. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the documentation:

-transparent
...

Note that this does not define the color as being the 'transparency color' used for color-mapped image formats, such as GIF. **For that use -transparent-color**